# Securing Google App Engine Endpoints

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am currently pretty new to Java and developing Android apps, and I depend on Google to learn most of what I have done for my first app so far. I am currently implementing Google App Engine on my app using Eclipse. I am able to write the backend API and generate endpoints just fine for my app. My app is able to make the correct calls and retrieve information from my datastore. However, I am a bit confused as to how the backend actually works behind the scene and am a bit worried about the security of my datastore.

**My questions are:**

1) Who would be able to access my endpoints? So far, I checked Google API Explorer and cannot see any methods for my endpoints. Can someone decompile my APK, find my app id, and create an app that can call my endpoint's methods? I understand I can secure it by using client ids and such, but if someone was able to forge this, would they gain access to my endpoint methods?

2) Is my backend secure? Would someone be able to actually read the code on my backend? My assumption now is that the code I write in Eclipse and deploy to Google will be run on the server and my app code only contains the calls to it. (This may seem like a silly question, but I've been doing a lot of research and still can't find the answer).

-Edit- I have done more reading and I believe that someone will only be able to download and read the code if they have admin access to the app engine adminstration. As for the backend for my app, it is only an extended servlet. Someone can only access these methods if their client id matches with the ones I set up. Correct me if I am wrong please.

3) Is the only access to my datastore based on what I have written for the backend? So for example, I have a function called getUser() that gets information about the user from datastore. Will a person with access to my backend only be able to use the method getUser(), and wont be able to manually call datastore.get(userKey) (if said person was somehow able to get the key)?

**Research:**

I have looked up in securing my endpoints and am currently working on authenticating endpoint methods with client ID. I have also written my methods in such a way as to only return public information and no private information. I am just worried that someone who manages to decompile my app and recover all the information on it will be able to use my endpoints, or worse alter my backend. I am currently rereading through the docs on the app engine backend, but would appreciate any input on this matter.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right to worry.  See the Snowden revelations.  The following are educated guesses that you can try to confirm or dismiss.  If the answers are important you may need input from an ethical hacker.

1) An attacker has multiple opportunities to compromise the security of your client application.  I do not think the APK file format obfuscates the URLs of your endpoints.  The APK file is probably compressed in an industry standard way that anyone can expand.  Dumping the executable binary content of the APK will reveal its literal strings, endpoint names and much more.  Decompiling would go a step further by revealing your algorithms, a dependency graph of all methods and metadata about their parameters.  A debugger can probably single step and monitor your application as bytecode without needing the original source code.

Malware appears to be more widespread than most people think.  A compromised device can probably leak all your app traffic to a remote computer for analysis at practically zero cost to the attacker.  The relative ease with which Android apps can be published makes that ecosystem more vulnerable than iOS.  Every other installed app is potentially your enemy, especially if the user enables rooting.

Recent discoveries of compromised certificate authorities, DNS cache corruption, imposter hotspots and computer in the middle attacks show that a motivated attacker can log your specific HTTPS traffic without even accessing the client or server computers.  However the attacker needs to expend a small cost per victim so you are only at risk if your code and data are believed to have sufficient value.

Client identity theft or forgery is probably possible.  Basically item 1) boils down to security through obscurity being minimal security whose cost to crack may be low.

2) The back end software is as secure as your Google account, own computer and network connection.  Therefore pretty safe ;-)

3) There are two ways to access the data in your back end: through the API that you implement and through the Admin Console with your Google account.  If a hosting provider secretly gives others a back door they naturally won't admit it.  I believe there are authorities with the power to make that happen.  If I was truly paranoid about my application and its data I would distrust every platform.

In summary all security barriers must conditionally open and no security is absolute.  With explicit security code in your application you can hope to slow down an attack to the point where the attacker's cost to benefit ratio makes finding easier meat elsewhere more attractive.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I think this answers all of the questions I have for the security of my backend. So while a hacker may be able to access and use my endpoints, they will not be able to read its actual code. That's really all I am worried about. Thanks!